# Integration Sharepoint Foundation 2013 and Microsoft Oulook

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, outlook

i am going to implement sharepoint for our company and i wanna make integration between sharepoint2013 and outlook mail!

is that a way to make have the list of inbox mails and sent mail in sharepoint?!!!

Answer (score 0):

What is the actual goal around doing this?  Depending on what you are trying to achieve there may be some options.

If it's just to have a single URL to go to from SharePoint. Foundation doesn't have the webparts for webmail integration out of the box, you would have to create a custom webpart or solution to hook into the Exchange API to handle this.

As an alternative you could just embed the link to Web Mail or even use the page viewer webpart to show OWA inside of a SharePoint page.

If you goal is to reduce storage on Exchange you could mail enable a folder and CC all messages to it - this would store a copy of the .eml file inside a document library.